# javascript - clone DOM body without script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am developing a chrome extension in which I need to clone the body tag-childrens. (a clone - so that the elements does not get updated when the DOM changes). And Re-append them to the body tag, without the script tags. 
*I am doing this to avoid the script tags for executing.*

**The problem** is that I don't want script tags cloned along with the other elements in the body. I read that using regex to filter/search for stuff in the html is general [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7123519).

How can I accomplish my goals, what are my options?

Comment: What do you mean by *"so that the elements does not get updated when the DOM is edited"*? I doubt you can prevent the existing script tags from executing

Comment: If I store an array of eg. all p_tags in the DOM, and then clear the entire DOM. Then all the p_tags in that array would be gone too. Therefor I would like to clone the elements, so that when the DOM is cleared, the p_tags won't be affected.

Answer (score 2):

A vanilla javascript approach might look like the following.

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;

div.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(function(scriptTag) {
  scriptTag.parentNode.removeChild(scriptTag);
});

document.body.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div>
  A div
</div>

<script>
  console.log('hi');
</script>

<p>
  A paragraph
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you could try something like:

```
var $clone = $('<div>').append($('body').html())
    $clone.find('script').remove()
```

Then when you want to replace:

```
$('body').html($clone.html())
```

Note that all event listeners will be lost with this approach

Comment: What would a none-jQuery implementation look like?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with jQuery if you didn't want a jQuery example?

Comment: It's not that I don't want a jQuery example, I am just curious how it would be written without the use of jQuery.

Comment: what does "$('<div>')" ?

Comment: Creates a `<div>` element

Comment: For some reason I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" even though the jQuery library is imported (Yes it is imported in the head as one of the first). This is the website: https://www.business.dk/ledelse/kom-med-ind-i-magtens-korridorer-2018-hvilke-topchefer-stiger-i-graderne-og

Comment: Try changing `$` to `jQuery` and make sure the library loads before your code does